# CSS: Layout from <span> elements only

Tags: html, css

I have this exercise of making a simple layout of four boxes. No containers/placeholders are allowed and only four `<span>` elements should be in `<body>`. All CSS should be written inline. When maximizing the browser the layout should be centered. Box 1 should be at the top and Box 4 at the bottom. Between them, Box 2 and 3 should sit next to eachother. So far I've done Box 1 and 4, but I'm having trouble with 2 and 3. I've put `float:left` on them, but that didn't work with `margin:auto`.

Another thing that I don't understand is that only Box 4 should be left/visible when the browser is resized to it's smallest size. I have checked all my books and searched the web, but I have still no clue how to do it. No Javascript or similar is allowed.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CSS-exercise</title>
</head>
<body >
<span style="background-color:#ccffe5; width:800px; height:200px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 1</span> 
    <span style="background-color:#cce0ff; width:750px; height:500px;">Box 2</span>
    <span style="background-color:#ffccdd; width:50px; height:500px;">Box 3</span>  
    <span style="background-color:#ffcc99; width:800px; height:400px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 4</span> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try adding display:block to your span.

Comment: Spans are inline elements, as @CatalinCislariu suggests you will need to change the display property for any width/height to be applied.

Comment: You don't name it in your description, but you seem to be working under the constraint that the block of boxes should be centered. Was that part of the assignment, or are you making things unneccesarily difficult for yourself?

Comment: @Andreas Eriksson It doesn't say so explicitly, only that the layout should stay consistent when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, if any other thing required,please let me know -

```
<body >
<span style="background-color:#ccffe5; width:800px; height:200px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 1</span> 
    <span style="background-color:#cce0ff; width:750px; height:500px; display:inline-block">Box 2</span>
    <span style="background-color:#ffccdd; width:50px; display:inline-block; height:500px;">Box 3</span>  
    <span style="background-color:#ffcc99; width:800px; height:400px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 4</span> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
<span style="background-color:#ccffe5; width:800px; height:200px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 1</span> 
<span style="background-color:#cce0ff; width:400px; height:500px; display:inline-block;">Box 2</span>
<span style="background-color:#ffccdd; width:400px; height:500px; display:inline-block;">Box 3</span>  
<span style="background-color:#ffcc99; width:800px; height:400px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 4</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it. it will work for you.

```
<span style="background-color:#ccffe5; width:800px; height:100px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 1</span>
<span style="background-color:#cce0ff; width:800px; height:100px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 2</span> 
<span style="background-color:#ffccdd; width:800px; height:100px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 3</span> 
<span style="background-color:#ffcc99; width:800px; height:100px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 4</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something this:

```html
<body style="text-align: center">
<span style="background-color:#ccffe5; width:800px; height:200px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 1</span> 
<span style="background-color:#cce0ff; width:750px; height:500px;  display:inline-block">Box 2</span>
<span style="background-color:#ffccdd; width:50px; height:500px; display:inline-block">Box 3</span>  
<span style="background-color:#ffcc99; width:800px; height:400px; display:block; margin:auto;">Box 4</span> 
</body>
```

I gave "display: inline-block" for Box 2 and Box 4. Futhermore gave for body "text-align: center".

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes